# Stochastic process vs. random function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, random-variables

On the [wiki page on stochastic processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process?wprov=sfti1#Stochastic_process), it says that they can be interpreted as random elements of a function space, which makes complete sense to me. However, it goes on to say that this interpretation requires “additional regularity assumptions” to be well defined, and references some old analysis paper. I tried reading it, but quickly realizied it to be way above my level. Could someone with a better understanding explain what these regularity assumptions are?